# Has Chrome stopped supporting Intl function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-intl

I am using chrome browser (Version 92.0.4515.131).

I found that the support for JavaScript Intl is not functioning properly in **Chrome** browser.

```js
const formattedDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('nb-NO', {
  "year": "numeric",
  "month": "2-digit",
  "day": "2-digit"
}).format(new Date('2021-08-02'));

console.log(formattedDate);
```

Chrome is giving "08/02/2021" as a result, instead of the expected "02.08.2021" like in Firefox.

The JavaScript functionality is defined in [ECMA](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#datetimeformat-objects) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) mention for the browser compatibility.

Is there is any modification we need to add in order for this to work properly in Chrome?

Comment: "Chrome is not" — you need to tell us the behaviour you get as well as the behaviour you expect.

Comment: The expected behavior for the above code snippet is -"02.08.2021"
but what chrome returns is - "08/02/2021"

Comment: by searching on can I use https://caniuse.com/?search=Intl it seem that chrome still support it, so you will have to explain what is the output and what did you tried

Comment: @Seren I have tried the above code snippet in chrome browser console, which gave me the output of, "08/02/2021"
but what it is expected to return is, "02.08.2021"

Answer (score 4):

See [Intl.ListFormat.supportedLocalesOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/ListFormat/supportedLocalesOf)

When I run `Intl.ListFormat.supportedLocalesOf(['en', 'de', 'nb'])` in Chrome and Firefox:

- Chrome reports that it supports English and German
- Firefox reports that it supports English, German and Norwegian

The problem isn't lack of support for  `Intl` (which would throw an error if it wasn't supported) but the `nb-NO` locale specifically.

Comment: yes it seems at the time chrome is not supporting 'nb'. 
thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue with chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1233509&q=locale&can=2

Hopefully it will be solved soon.